# how to get random data along with groupby from relations?

Tags: laravel

I have `vehicles` table that has relation with `vehicle_Model` and `vehicle` `vehicle_vendor` table.

Now I want to generate only **3 random rows/tuple** each time page refreshes.

I have already tried this but when using `->groupBy()` it does not generate random data.

```
$models = VehicleModel::has('vehicle')->inRandomOrder()->pluck('id')->take(3);

return Vehicle::has('vehicleModel')->has('vehicleModel.vehicleVendor')->whereIn('vehicle_model_id',$models)->with(['vehicleModel','vehicleModel.vehicleVendor'])->inRandomOrder()->take(3)->groupBy(['vehicle_model_id',])->get()->pluck('id');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution instead of using group by looping through the vehicle_model_id works

```
$vehicles = [];

foreach($models as $model){

$vehicles = Vehicle::where('vehicle_model_id',$model)->with(['vehicleModel','vehicleModel.vehicleVendor'])->inRandomOrder()->first();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have your `->pluck('id')` and `->take(3)` in the wrong order. You are also not using `->get()` to complete your query.

`->pluck()` is a collection method used **after** completing the eloquent query once a collection object is returned. To select what fields you would like to get **before** completing the query you should be able to use `->select()`.

However, to solve your issue:

```
$models = VehicleModel::has('vehicle')
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->take(3)
    ->get()
    ->pluck('id')
    ->all();
```

This should return an array with 3 random model `id`s to use in your other query. `->all()` is used to convert the collection object into an array.

From here, you need to remove your `->whereIn()` as it is checking against the `Vehicle` and not the `VehicleModel`. You can extend the `->with()` call like so:

```
...

->with(['vehicleModel' => function ($query) use ($models) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $models);
}, 'vehicleModel.vehicleVendor'])

...
```

This will only add vehicle models which have an `id` contained in the `$models` array.

I hope this helps.